# How to develop telerik report viewer using .net framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, telerik

I am developing application which is integrated with  sharepoint 2010 webpart using .net 
framework 3.5,I need to build telerik report viewer dynamically via c# code.I have created new asp.net project with framework 3.5 but I could not add reference of Telerik.Reporting.dll and Telerik.Reporting.WebForms.dll.It is possible if the project framework is 4.0 but sharepoint 2010 does not supports framework 4.0 i(we cannot include framework 4.0 dlls into wsp) file.How can I use report viewer in .net framework 3.5 with sharepoint 2010 support  and include those .net framework dlls into wsp file?

Let me know which version of telerik report viewer supports .net framework 3.5 and where can I get it.

Note: I am using latest release(2013 Q3) of report viewer.

Regards,

RanjithKumar.G

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Repoting has not supported .NET Framework 2.0 - 3.5 since the Q2 2013 version (http://blogs.telerik.com/telerikreportingteam/posts/13-01-21/telerik-reporting-to-drop-.net2.x-.net3.0-vs2005-and-vs2008-support-in-q2-2013). You may download an older version 7.0.13.220 for example.